# How to test if all elements in a array have the same value in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to write a simple program that uses Julia to test if all elements of an array are the same. Is there a simple way to do this in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allunique` tests if all elements of an array are *unique*. In order to test if all elements of an array are the same you can write e.g.:

```
function allequal(itr)
    local x
    isfirst = true
    for v in itr
        if isfirst
            x = v
            isfirst = false
        else
            isequal(x, v) || return false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

and now you have

```
julia> allequal([1,2,3])
false

julia> allequal([1,2,1])
false

julia> allequal([1,1,1])
true
```

You could write a shorter function like e.g.:

```
f1(itr) = length(Set(itr)) <= 1
```

but it probably will be slower (I have not run the benchmarks).

or you could write something like:

```
f2(itr) = length(itr) == 0 ? true : all(isequal(itr[1]), itr)
```

if your iterable has `length` defined and supports indexing.

Comment: Great catch and answer. Sorry about that. Had a little bit of a brain malfunction there :)

Comment: `all( isequal(first(itr)), itr)` also works if the iterator doesn't support indexing, no?

Comment: Yes, but you have to check that `itr` is not empty additionally as a special case.

Comment: also `first` might alter the state of some iterables, and in general if they support `getindex` it is rather safe to assume that using it will not affect it.

Answer (score 3):

```
length(itr)==0 || all( ==(itr[1]), itr)
```

This seems to be 3x faster than the proposed `allequal` function.

Some benchmarks:

```
julia> allequal_2(itr) = length(itr)==0 || all( ==(itr[1]), itr);

julia> const vv = ones(10000000)*3;

julia> @btime allequal($vv)
  13.212 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
true

julia> @btime allequal_2($vv)
  4.178 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
true
```

What is even more interesting it is 2x faster than the proposed very similar `f2` function:

```
julia> @btime f2($vv)
  9.509 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Nice! My own best effort was `21.346 ms (2 allocations: 76.29 MiB)`, so this drastically reduces the work. Apparently `itr[1]` can be replaced with `first(itr)` with no penalty. And wrapping it all in a parametric type also has no penalty either, as far as I could see. Removing the length check did not increase speed. The deal breaker here is replacing Bogumił's `isequal` with `==`. Who would have thought! But then reading https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/ suggests probably the reason is `isequal` checks for `NaN` and `missing`.

Comment: Yes `==(_)` is the fastest option. Similarly you have `>(_)`, `<(_)` etc,